# Ubuntu 17.04: Terminal not opening when clicked on - how get terminal to work properly?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

The terminal icon is present, but the terminal does not open when clicked on. How do I get the terminal to open and work?

Comment: Your Ubuntu is not supported anymore. Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) on how to upgrade to a newer release. But regarding your issues, it would be probably much easier, faster and better to backup your data and install a supported release from scratch.

Comment: You may ask a question on how to backup your *locked files*, which is weird ...

Comment: I'm trying to get a terminal so i can unlock the files and remove them. Also, i don't have a terminal so i can not do the upgrade to a newer release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always consider the possibility that you don't have malware but did something wrong yourself, in which case it should be possible to fix it with normal commands.

If you indeed got malware on your computer, stop using the installed operating system ASAP.

Boot the computer from a live CD/DVD and save the files that you need to an external drive (an USB stick for example). Be careful not to copy executables or scripts that may be part of the malware.

After everything is saved, do a complete reinstall of the operating system (the current version, not 17.04 again), create the user account and copy the files you need back to the disk. If you preserved the directory structure of your home directory, desktop files should appear on the desktop again.

If you're unsure about how to do all of this, get someone knowledgeable to help you. They will appreciate receiving a favor in return, some won't even say no to some money :-)

Comment: Well, I used a live dvd w/ ubuntu 18.04 or the latest one, but i don't see my files, though I didn't expect to since they are saved on the hdd. With the live dvd, how am i supposed to recover my desktop files from my hdd? If someone remotely caused this terminal, etc, issue, my guess would be that they maliciously altered a directory.Thanks for the help.

Comment: PUT ON HOLD: what I am asking? The terminal window icon is present, but when I try to open it, it does not open. I need to know how to get my terminal window to function again. If I can not get my terminal window to open with suggestions, then my next question is, how can I transfer my 'locked' files from this desktop to other media.

Comment: When you start from the live dvd your hdd should be present as a drive on the desktop. As I said if you don't know how to access it from the live dvd, ask someone who knows. It is impossible to give step-by-step advice in the comments of a stack exchange article, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the desktop, you can try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and then type **`gnome-terminal`** and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see if you can get it fired up.

If for some reason `gnome-terminal` does nothing, try the same thing but this time using **`xterm`**

Comment: Terminal commands with 'alt f2' not working, but thanks anyway.